# Where can I find data sets that have no API?

Tags: data-request, api

I am putting together a tutorial on how to build APIs and I was curious if there are any open data sets that do not have an API attached to it.

Comment: On what topic? The web is full of datasets.

Comment: pretty much anything. The tutorial is aimed at programmers and non-programmers to show how easy it is to turn a large data set into an API.

Comment: What do you qualify as 'no-API'?  There are libraries and toolkits for working with existing formats.  Eg, so that you can interface w/ CSV data without having to write the CSV parsing yourself.  If you're looking for data that's available as an existing web service, this may not suffice as an API (and thus, what you're looking for)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option would be to look at the datasets registered to a US government agency on [Data.gov](http://catalog.data.gov) and then contract that list against [known APIs](http://18f.github.io/API-All-the-X/pages/status) from that agency.

So - for instance, filter for [datasets from the US Department of Transportation on Data.gov](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?_organization_limit=0&organization=dot-gov) and compare that list against the [APIs listed for the Department of Transportation on this page](http://18f.github.io/API-All-the-X/pages/individual_apis) (Cmd/Ctrl+F for 'Federal Aviation Administration' and start there).

*Disclaimer: I am Sr. API Strategist at the General Services Administration.*

Comment: Very nice idea!

Answer (score 3):

[ICPSR at the University of Michigan](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/index.jsp) has a bunch of social science-type datasets, which might work for you.

Answer (score 2):

- Hackernews' list of on databases: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2165497
- US GOV: https://www.data.gov/open-gov/